# Why first ..draggable classes drops twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two container left side , right side , I drag element from left and puts in right side, the left side container has two types one is cloned after drag and another removed , so I have placed two drag drop , first one is dropping twice  .

Cloned after dragged:

```
<ul class='list-inline edit_audit_container edit_draggable elementUl>
<li class='item'>
<input type='text' readonly>
</li>
</ul>
```

This one removed after dragged:

```
<ul class='list-inline audit_container draggable elementUl>
<li class='item'>
<input type='text' readonly>
</li>
</ul>
```

Dragged in this container

```
<div class="wid30c1 border droppable draggablemain">                                    
 </div>
```

image link : https://prnt.sc/q3skww

```js
$(function () {
   $('.draggable').draggable({
revert: "invalid",
stack: "0",
helper: 'clone'
});
   // above codes drops twice

$('.edit_draggable').draggable({
revert: "true",
stack: "0"
});
$('.droppable').droppable({
accept: ".draggable,.edit_draggable",
drop: function (event, ui) {
 $(this).find("input").remove();
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    draggable.clone().appendTo(droppable);
   $(this).find("input").attr("name", "headercols[]");  
}
});
});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant html, without it we can't really help you.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen added html

Comment: Your HTML has Syntax errors. You're not closing all your attributes properly.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to have happen when an item is dropped. Do you want the items to be cloned? Or removed? Please edit your post and include the desired outcome of all the potential actions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    stack: "0",
    start: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Drag Start", ui.helper.attr("class"));
    }
  });

  $('.edit_draggable').draggable({
    stack: "0",
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Drag Start", ui.helper.attr("class"));
    }
  });

  $('.droppable').droppable({
    accept: "ul[class*='draggable']",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).html("");
      var droppable = $(this);
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      console.log("Drop", draggable.attr("class"));
      var c = draggable.clone().attr("style", "").appendTo(droppable);
      if (draggable.hasClass("draggable")) {
        draggable.remove();
      }
      $(this).find("input").attr("name", "headercols[]");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.left-col {
  width: 170px;
  float: left;
}

.list-inline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.list-inline input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.droppable {
  width: 300px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 20px;
  margin-left: 225px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.draggable input {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.edit_draggable input {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="left-col">
  <ul class='list-inline edit_audit_container edit_draggable elementUl'>
    <li class='item'>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span><input type='text' readonly>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul class='list-inline audit_container draggable elementUl'>
    <li class='item'>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span><input type='text' readonly>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="wid30c1 border droppable draggablemain">
</div>
```

You will have slightly different drop conditions for a `clone` versus the actual draggable.